# HTML table to Excel --> TEMP File could not be found?

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, html-table

I need to put a certain table into an Excel table. 
I am using the solution to this question:
[HTML Table to Excel Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript)

I left the JS unchanged, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function () {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function (table, name, filename) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

    document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
    document.getElementById("dlink").click();
}
})()
</script>
```

This is the HTML I use to trigger the download:
The anchor:

```
<a id="dlink" href="#testTable" style="display:none;"></a>
```

The button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'testTable', 'myExport.xls')" value="Export to Excel">
```

The table attributes:

```
<table data-name="testTable" id="testTable" summary="All members" rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2">
```

Once I click the button, it opens Excel and gives me the following error:

> 'C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\myExport.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling (insert rest of microsoft BLA here)

Any help appreciated!

Just found out the following:
IE == NOT EVEN WORKING
Chrome == Gives me file, but leaves some fields filled with the value 'тВм0'.
FireFox == 'C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\myExport.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling (insert rest of microsoft BLA here)

Comment: Hmm, i got it fully working in chrome now. But FireFox seems to still not agree to what i want to do. Is there a way to force-download ? that would eliminate the chances of the file not exsisting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this topic received 0 feedback i found this thread after searching a while.
[html to excel export with .xls extension in javascript or php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425270/html-to-excel-export-with-xls-extension-in-javascript-or-php)

This gave me the solution. I hope it helps others too.